# making a outside-class variable global within class

Tags: php, class, variables, global

say i have a `db` instance which is created outside of my class say called `Foo`, how do I make this `db` variable globally accessible within my `Foo` class?

I know i can have `global db;` within any functions that want to access it within `Foo()`, but how would I make it global to the class so I could call it by `$this->db;`

Comment: I don't get it. Do you want to extend `Foo` to contain `db`. Then be able to call the `db` class from within `Foo` and effect the `db` class? You did use the word instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a singleton

```
class MyDB {
  private static $instance;
  private $dbh;

  private function __construct() {}

  public static function getInstance() {
    if( !self::$instance ) {
      self::$instance = new MyDB();
    }
    return self::$instance;
  }

  public function init($host, $user, $pass) {
      $this->dbh = new PDO(); // or whatever
  }
}

class MyClass {
  private $dbh;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->dbh = MyDB::getInstance();
  }
}

$dbh = MyDB::getInstance();
$dbh->init('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
$mine = new MyClass(); // internal dbh is initialized and ready to go, no globals required.
```

Answer (score 2):

Theorem [as always, rare special cases apply]:

> **Any developer should try to avoid global variables in any programming language.**

Please wrap `db` inside of a class and establish a well defined interface by means of methods:

```
class CDb { 

  protected $_instance;

  public function getInstance() { 
    return $this->_instance;
  }

  public function setInstance( $newInstance ) { 
    $this->_instance = $newInstance;
  }

}

class CFoo {

  public function doSomething( CDB $aDB ) { 

    print_r( $aDB->getInstance() );

  } 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work this out in a few ways, the way I would do it is make the `db` a static attribute and assign it to `$this->db` in the constructor if needed, like so:

```
class Foo {

    private $db;

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = System::$db;
    }

}
```

or even better, you could create a method `System::getDB()` and make `$db` within it a Singleton :

```
static function getDB() {
    if (self::$db == null) {
        self::$db = new Database();
    }
    return self::$db;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

```
var $db = new mysqli(/*arguments*/);
class Foo{
  public $db;
  public function __construct($database){
    $this->db = $database;
  }
}
$foo = new Foo($db); $dtb = $foo->db;
```